# jQuery and setTimeout: TypeError: g.nodeName is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, typeerror, nodename

I'm having problems with a script. I'm using a jQuery.post function inside a setTimout and it returns `TypeError: g.nodeName is undefined` on Firebug. Here's my script:

```
jQuery(function($) {
var timer;

    $("#tabela-orcamento .item .item-qtd .qtd-item").keyup(function() {     
        clearTimeout(timer);

        timer = setTimeout(function() {         
            $.post("../../aj_orc.php?op=atualizaQtd", {
                item: $(this).parents(".item").attr("data-item"),
                qtd: $(this).val()
            }, function(data) {
                $("#retornos").html(data);
            });
        },1000);
    });
});
```

Is something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Your running into a problem, because the `this` inside your timeout refers to another context as you might think. Just introduce another `that` as a intermediate variable:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var timer;

    $("#tabela-orcamento .item .item-qtd .qtd-item").keyup(function() {     
        clearTimeout(timer);

        var $that = $(this);
        timer = setTimeout(function() {         
            $.post("../../aj_orc.php?op=atualizaQtd", {
                item: $that.parents(".item").attr("data-item"),
                qtd: $that.val()
            }, function(data) {
                $("#retornos").html(data);
            });
        },1000);
    });
});
```